# sbt-native-packager Unknown artifact in Inellij

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am new to scala and I am trying to deploy a test application to another machine.  To do this, I need all the dependancies to come with the deployment.  In my search for methods to accomplish this I fount the sbt-native-packager. The README on git up says to add the following to plugins.stb:
`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.5.1")`

When I do this, Intellij states that it is an unknown artifact even after I re-import the project.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you really add this to `project/plugins.sbt`? Also, please post the complete error message, we need more context here.

Comment: BTW, if you simply want to create a fat jar, which you can run with `java -jar xya.jar`, better have a look at the `sbt-assembly` plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @cbley. I found the issue.  It turns out that URL that sbt was attempting to download from was incorrect.  I had to add `resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)` to `plugins.stb` In addition to that change, I also had to set down the version of sbt I was running to `1.2.8` . Thanks for the tip on the java command as well. I am new to scala but I also do not know java! It's a lot to take in coming from Python and R.